# Is it possible to inject a dll with c# code and override a return value?

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection

Lets say there is a simple c# application that is running which returns the answer for 1+1 in the form of a int with a value of 2, and I have the sourcecode for it but for curiosity's sake I want to change what it does without modifying the dll before runtime.

Is it possible to inject the running application with your own .dll and change the answer it returns in the same class & method to a value of something besides 2?

I already know I can go into the memory while the program is running and theoretically change the answer of "2" to something else, I'm curious if I can change the programs logic as it does it.

I also already know it's possible to "extend" running applications by injecting another .dll and "adding" additional functionality to an application, I'm interested in the theoretical possibility to change the code that is already running in the original .dll.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are wanting to do `Your application ----> External DLL Function call -> External DLL Function call result --(modification of the result value here)--> Your application`

Comment: Look too broad for me... Yes, it is possible to change any code that is running now (except tiny portion that already in CPU pipeline). To get practical answers (i.e. something outside hacking tools) - please explain what your real goal is.

Comment: I am wanting to change the original dll's return value, without recompiling, or disassembling/modifying/reassembling, etc. Basically, change the sourcecode of the application while it's running by injecting it with an external dll with the new code. I'm just wondering if it's possible at this point, I'm not interested in how.

Clarification: by changing sourcecode at runtime, I don't expect it to stay that way when I close the application. Just a one-time change (unless injected every time).

Comment: @Alexei thanks for your answer, my goal is just to satisfy curiosity. I now know it's possible, I'm wondering how possible it is now (just as going to the moon is possible, but not practical for everyone).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not easy to "change" the code inside a external DLL, however if you want to modify a argument going in or a result coming back that is not hard to do. The process of intercepting the call to either modify the input or output is called "[Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)".

In C# there is a easy to use library that does most of the work for you called [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/), this will allow you to intercept calls and replace the return values with your own results.

```
static IntPtr CreateFile_Hooked(
    String InFileName, 
    UInt32 InDesiredAccess, 
    UInt32 InShareMode, 
    IntPtr InSecurityAttributes,
    UInt32 InCreationDisposition, 
    UInt32 InFlagsAndAttributes, 
    IntPtr InTemplateFile)
{
    try
    {
        Main This = (Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback;

        lock (This.Queue)
        {
        if (This.Queue.Count < 1000)
                This.Queue.Push(InFileName);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    // call original API...
    return CreateFile(
        InFileName, 
        InDesiredAccess, 
        InShareMode, 
        InSecurityAttributes, 
        InCreationDisposition,
        InFlagsAndAttributes, 
        InTemplateFile);
}
```

In the above code it takes the argument passed in to `InFileName` and records it for later use inside your external mointoring program. You could easily just capture the result returned from `CreateFile` (or whatever real dll function you are calling) modify it to be whatever you want, then return the modified value.

To the caller of the original function they would have no idea that the value they got back from the DLL call was modified before they received it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot, I will choose this as answer as soon as it lets me (4 min countdown), if you're still around, I'm curious now as to why methods/classes can't be tweaked with like return results?

Comment: You can modify the code in a class, but like I said it is not easy. You need to [emit IL code](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570) in to the CLR to replace the code that was previously in the assembly (a much more advanced topic that I do not know anything about other than the fact that it exists)

Comment: Scott Chamberlain I have been looking over this again and I'm curious why you have to write a "U" in the "UInt32" part. Also are you using IntPtr because of a theoretical 64-bit program?

So is the "CreateFile" in the "CreateFile_hooked" the class in the source .dll or program you are hooking into? Is the "UInt32 IsDesiredAccess" and others similar to it the return value parameter names in the source code?

Comment: `CreateFile_hooked` is intercepting [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which comes in the dll `Kernel32.dll` that comes with windows. The `U` is used because the method signature requires a Unsigned int. IntPtr is used because `CreateFile` returns a 32 bit pointer on 32 bit systems and 64 bit pointer on 64 bit systems. The code I posted came [from this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking). Your last question I did not understand.